# CMS or Wiki for creating XHTML ebook + blog

Tags: python, wordpress, content-management-system, wiki, docbook

For a long time I have been wanting to start a blog. But knowing myself, I know I won't update it often. So, I would like to club my blog with an "**ebook**". I'd like to write some beginner level ebook/course on **Biostatistics**.

Here are some examples of other blogs (+ebooks) that follow this approach:

- A Byte of Python: http://www.swaroopch.com/notes/Python
- BabyPips (FX trading): http://www.babypips.com/school/
- Learn Python the Hard way (ebook only): http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/

I could simply use WordPress or Tumblr or some blog site to create a blog and write my tutorials there. One post for each tutorial. BUT I am leaning towards creating a more structured book with **table-of-contents**, **sequential chapters**, **prev/next navigation**, and even **quizzes** *(if possible)* etc. Blog-post style is better suited for independent tutorials that don't follow a structured course/book format.

For **Blog** section, there is WordPress etc. But I haven't figured out how to create a structured **ebook** like these guys have created. What software/plugin/CMS/wiki plugin to use for this?

PS: eventually, I'd also like to convert my web ebook to PDF, MOBI, EPUB format. But that is probably not hard. Most important is to publish a web ebook like these guys have done it.

**UPDATE**:

Ideally, I just want to be able to login and click create-> new book or new chapter or something and just write like I'd write in a WYSIWYG editor. That script should take care of generating table of content and navigation etc. I think this probably resemebles wiki script but wiki-script probably won't take care of next/prev navigation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.swaroopch.com/notes/Python uses [MediaWiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki), which is okay for writing books. If you want to publish in several formats, a sophisticated markup language like [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) or [reStructuredText](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html) might be more appropriate. You can use different utilities to create static web pages using those, like [Sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/), [Hyde](http://ringce.com/hyde) or [Jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/).

Comment: Thanks. I looked at these formats. I am not really a coder per se. What I am looking for is a rather WYSIWYG tool to integrate with my blog. Ideally, I just want to be able to login and click create-> new book or new chapter or something and just write like I'd write in a WYSIWYG editor. I am confused as to whats the point of writing in Markdown, or reStructuredText format. How does that fit in with my blog/WordPress?

Comment: @Red Char: It's all about efficiency. Markdown, for example, is a very simple plain text format that you can used to structure your documents. It can be compiled into LaTeX (PDF), XHTML or even ODT. If you want WYSIWYG, you better stick with your existing Blog engine (like Wordpress or so). But if you begin writing text in plain format, you will soon realize how efficient that can be.

Comment: Also, please update your question with the additional information you gave in your comment. This was not clear at all. And if you don't want to use a general purpose markup format, you really need to reconsider the assumption that conversion to other formats is "probably not hard"

Comment: Thanks. I see what you mean. The problem I am trying to tackle is not which format to use. Ultimately, I want my book to be online so ultimately it'd be HTML. I just dont want to have to create static html site for each chapter and then manually create/update a table of content. And then FTP it to my server. Instead, I wanted a script/software that would take care of it all. Similar to how WordPress takes care of bogging piece. I just login, and create a new post. I've updated my question for clarification.

Comment: Well all the formats I described have ToC support. Recreating static pages and FTP upload can be automated (and has been automated for example by [webgen](http://webgen.rubyforge.org/)). I think that your requirements are too narrow to find an exact solution to your problem.

Comment: Ok. How about we broaden my requirements. What would be the easiest workflow to create a blog+ebook site. Blog being WordPress or something similar and Ebook can be a combination of tools; and how would I integrate static ebook pages inside blog site/engine/wordpress?

Comment: @Red Char: Markdown, Textile and reStructuredText integration exists for Wordpress and a lot of other blog software. Also, you can easily integrate static XHTML in most blog software. If you want full automation of the publishing process, you'd probably need to hack something together on your own, however. Something like updating a database column from a script or similar.

Comment: I came across some help authoring tools like http://www.helpiq.com/make-help-documentation and DrExplain - maybe this is what people use to author a book, table of contents, generate static html, and then ftp upload it?

Comment: @Red Char: Most people prefer not to pay money for things you can get for free, so probably no. There is one more thing that comes to my mind you can look at: http://readthedocs.org/

Comment: I found that Drupal has "book" module!